# How can I reallocate array which allocated in another function?

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, realloc

I'm new to C programming.
I want to make a linked list, so I did, but it doesn't work.
After I do that, I made it for a test, but still it gives an error.

> malloc:  error for object 0xa000000000000000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
>   
> set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

How can I reallocate this array?

```
void Allocate(int **arr,int totalNum, int subNum)
{
    for(int n=0;n<(totalNum+1);n++)
    {
        arr[n] = (int*)realloc(arr[n],(size_t)((subNum+1)*sizeof(int)));
    }
}
int main()
{
    int totalNum = 20;
    int subNum = 5;
    int **arr;
    arr = (int**)malloc((totalNum+1)*sizeof(int*));
    Allocate(arr,totalNum, subNum);

    for(int n=1;n<(totalNum+1);n++)
    {
        for(int s=1;s<(subNum+1);s++)
        {
            arr[n][s] = rand()%5;
            cout<<"arr["<<n<<"]["<<s<<"]: "<<arr[n][s]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't begin to understand the question. Linked lists and arrays are different things, if you're unaware

Comment: *I'm newb on C programming.* -- Why did you tag this as `C++`?  C++ has `std::list` if you want a douby-linked list, a `std::forward_list` for a singly-linked list, and `std::vector` for dynamic errors.  Thus there is no need for coding to look like this.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: C is not C++, please make the tag and the question body match. Never ever use malloc or realloc or arrays or raw pointers in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The program crashes because `arr[n]` is uninitialized when `realloc()` is invoked.

i do not fully understand why you want to `realloc()` instead of `malloc()` in the `Allocate()` function. but anyway, let's assume `realloc()` is what you need.

the easiest fix is to initialize `arr` content.

```
arr = (int**)calloc((totalNum+1),sizeof(int*));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `realloc()` has to be either `NULL` or a pointer that was returned earlier by `malloc()` or `realloc()`. You passed an array full of uninitialized data to `Allocate()`, so you're passing uninitialized pointers to `realloc()` there. You need to initialize them all to `NULL` first.

```
arr = malloc((totalNum+1)*sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < totalNum+1; i++) {
    arr[i] = NULL;
}
Allocate(arr,totalNum, subNum);
```